# Flex Builder Debugger doesn't display local variables

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, debugging, flex3, flexbuilder

I am using the Flex Builder 3 debugger almost every day and it's starting to be a real pain that the 'Variables' tab in the 'Flex Debugging' view doesn't show local variables, only 'this' is displayed.

Also I can not add Watch Expressions for local variables.

Am I forgetting something here or is the debugger just very limited?

Thanks

Comment: I just double-checked, but I've got no problems viewing local variables in my flex debugger. Unfortunately I don't have a clue what might be causing your debugger to not show them.

Comment: Sounds like it might be time to reinstall Flex Builder. I've never had this problem happen and been developing with Flex for 4+ years.

Comment: I used to be able to see private local variables without any problems but that capability is gone.  I can only see public variables.  The hover still works for me.  I too, have been hitting the Out of Memory errors.  In fact, it was around the time the memory errors started that I noticed private vars not showing in the debugger.  Has re-installing worked for anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem that motto described. Local variables are not displayed when debugging, "hover" method doesn't work either. You can always use `trace()` or Loging API.
The problem occurred to me yesterday and the only thing I noticed is that the project stopped to compile using ant script due to OutOfMemoryError (I usually build project using FB, but sometimes FlexBuilder doesn't show errors/warnings and compiling via ant script is the only way I know to find them).

Comment: The issue is quite funny because FB doesn't display local variables in one function and in another it does.

Answer (score 1):

To see if Flex Builder is even tracking your local variables properly, set a breakpoint somewhere in a function.  Once you hit that breakpoint, you can also "hover" over a variable in your source code, and a tooltip should show the current value of that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, FB has problems if the current function is further down in a larger file. Moving the function code up solves the problem (but exposes the same for another funciton further doen then). It seems that FB can only gather a certain amount of metadata for the currently open file.